# Onclick new window, changing element in new window

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using an onclick to open a link. I am trying to update an input box in the window using JS. I have tried to do this:

```
var str = "text";

<a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="window.open('https://jsfiddle.net/ncw1L0uk/show/');document.getElementById("input1").value=str;">link</a>
```

I am doing this in appscript inside a google form -> spreadsheet. An email is generated that gives the link, so I think I am limited to scripting inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either escape the double quotes or use single quotes instead:

```js
var str = "text";
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="input1" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('https://jsfiddle.net/ncw1L0uk/show/');document.getElementById('input1').value=str;">link</a>
```

or better use a function instead if appscript allows it:

```js
var str = "text";

function openAndChangeText() {
  window.open('https://jsfiddle.net/ncw1L0uk/show/');
  document.getElementById('input1').value=str;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="input1" />
<a href="javascript:openAndChangeText()">link</a>
```

*P.S. You won't get a popup in the above code snippets as popups are blocked in embedded fiddles (check your Developer Tools' Console).*

**Update 1**

If you want to change the text of an element within a newly opened window, you need to open it, wait until it has been loaded and then change the input's value.

```js
var str = "text";

function openAndChangeText() {
  var win= window.open('https://jsfiddle.net/ncw1L0uk/show/');
  win.onload= function() {
    win.document.getElementById('input1').value=str;
  }

}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:openAndChangeText()">link</a>
```

*The posted code again won't work in JSFiddle as popup policies prevent opening the window.*

**Update 2**

If you can't use a normal function, use a closure inside your link:

```html
<a href="javascript:(function() { var str= 'Test1'; var win= window.open('https://jsfiddle.net/ncw1L0uk/show/'); win.onload=function() { win.document.getElementById('input1').value=str;}})()">Click</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I need to clarify my question. The input box `id=input1` is on the page to be opened.

Comment: @redditor Ok, I missed that part. Try the "Update 1" example added to my answer, see if this works for you.

Comment: That's great, thank you! Is it possible to put this into inline script? So, for example, the entire script was inside the href?

Comment: @redditor then it's getting a bit ugly but a closure should help.